# How much time did Satan take to convince Adam to eat the fruit of forbidden tree?

Tags: adam-and-eve, prophet-adam

As Quran says

> And indeed, We once made a covenant with Adam, but he forgot, and ˹so˺
>   We did not find determination in him. [Quran 20:115]

How many years were they... that he just forgot??

Comment: I don't think there is any authentic source of information for this question.

Comment: Here the "forgot" is in the meaning of "erred" or "made a mistake." It does not mean literally forgot.